# Waiting for click in Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to wait for a click in Python Turtle before continuing. The code outline is as follows:

```
do_stuff()

# Wait for click and DO NOT continue if user has not clicked

# When user clicks:

do_other_stuff()

end()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713672/5757613) answer on SOF asks something similar, but the proposed solution involves extending the Turtle class. I remember using a simpler way to do this, but cannot recollect it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying turtle nor wizardry, you may have something working with [tirtle.onclick](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick).

```
do_stuff()
# Wait for click and DO NOT continue if user has not clicked
# When user clicks:
def second_part():
    turtle.onclick(None)
    do_other_stuff()
    end()
turtle.onclick(second_part)
turtle.mainloop()
```

You may even chain them manually (not tested):

```
do_stuff()

def third_part():
    turtle.onclick(None)
    ...

def second_part():
    turtle.onclick(third_part)
    ...

turtle.onclick(second_part)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting these lines at the end of the script worked pretty well for me

```
    def screenclick(x, y):
        exit()
       
    turtle.onscreenclick(screenclick)
    turtle.mainloop()
```